What exactly is code and how does it relate to law? Where does it fit into the hierarchy of law?
(I am not legally versed.) I am studying building and construction codes and am having some trouble understanding code in a general sense. First, how exactly is code defined? How is it distinct from law? Is code in the context of building and construction defined differently from code as in, for example, the U.S. Code? Second, what is the extent of building code and to what is it subject hierarchically? Is it the Constitution --> federal law --> state law --> building codes or does it go hand-in-hand with state law? As far as I can understand the building code itself as set out by the Constitution is fully determined by the States but within a State there may also be municipal code. There also seem to be cases such as NYC and Chicago where they have their own code and are not subject to State code. Anyways, you can see my confusion on the subject.
As a bonus, if someone could also explain regulations and how they tie into code I would really appreciate that.


how exactly is code defined? How is it distinct from law?

The word "code" means a comprehensive and logically organized statute. They are one kind of law.
A "code" can have subparts that are also called codes. For example, the codification of all of the laws in the state of Colorado is called the "Colorado Revised Statutes", but within the Colorado Revised Statutes are large, comprehensive statutes like the Uniform Commercial Code, the Probate Code, the Trust Code, and the Penal Code.
Shorter statutes enacted on a piecemeal basis are sometimes called "acts" rather than "codes" although there is no formal dividing line between the two. The only legal distinction between a code and an act is that the provisions of a code are expected to use words defined in the same way and to be internally consistent to a greater degree. Different acts can use the same words with different meanings, and all acts aren't intended to be read as a comprehensive whole in terms of how they are interpreted in isolation.
The U.S. federal government and U.S. state governments have a particularly low share of their laws in the form of comprehensive codes compared to most other countries.
In the U.S., many "codes" are drafted by private non-profit organizations as a model for governments to enact, and then adopted with minor local modification, by state or local governments.

The world's earliest known legal code: The Reforms of Urukagina, Sumeria. (2500 - 2350 BC)

Is code in the context of building and construction defined
differently from code as in, for example, the U.S. Code?

Not really.
The U.S. Code consists of the permanent statutes of the United States Congress organized in a subject matter fashion, and a building code is a well organized statute governing how structures are built.
In most U.S. states, building codes are adopted as local ordinances by county or municipal governments, generally adopting a particular version of a uniform building code promulgated by a private non-profit organization of building inspectors, with minor local modification.
In some U.S. states, however, they are adopted by the state government, or the state government enacts guidelines for how local governments could adopt them.
A municipal code consists of all the permanent ordinances of a city arranged on a subject-manner basis and would include the building codes adopted by the municipality.
The term ordinance refers to a statute adopted by a local government. The term statute refers to a law adopted by a legislative body like Congress, a state legislature, a county commission, or a city council, but in the case of statutes adopted by local governments, the term ordinance is preferred for clarity.
It is useful for building codes to be enacted as local ordinances because building codes are normally administered by local governments, and this facilitates enforcing building codes in municipal courts which are convenient for the local government and have judges that they typically appoint themselves.

what is the extent of building code and to what is it subject
hierarchically? Is it the Constitution --> federal law --> state law
--> building codes or does it go hand-in-hand with state law?

All laws in the U.S. are subordinate to the U.S. Constitution.
Federal law in the U.S. is supreme over state law in areas where the federal government is constitutionally permitted to, and has, legislated. Federal regulations are also supreme over state law in the constitutional supremacy sense.
The U.S. Constitution establishes a federal government that is, in principle, a "limited government", which can only legislate on specified topics subject to limitations like the Bill of Rights contained in the U.S. Constitution. In practice, there are few subjects that are beyond the legislative authority of the federal government, however, and the division between what is federal law and what is state law is more customary and political than it is a constitutional matter.
One of the reasons that lots of kinds of law is left to the states is that this deprives the federal courts of jurisdiction over these areas of law most of the time. The vast majority of civil and criminal cases are handled in state courts, rather than in federal courts.
As explained at Wikipedia:

For example, in Colorado, roughly 97% of all civil cases were filed in
state courts and 89% of the civil cases filed in federal court were
bankruptcies in 2002, a typical year. Just 0.3% of the non-bankruptcy
civil cases in the state were filed in federal court. . . .
As of 2019,
about 1,255,689 people currently behind bars in the United States—or
87.7% out of a total of 1,430,805 prisoners—had been convicted in state court for violating state criminal laws, rather than in federal
court for violating federal criminal laws.
The proportion of criminal cases brought in state court rather than
federal court is higher than 87.7% because misdemeanor and petty
offense prosecutions are disproportionately brought in state courts
and most criminal prosecutions involve misdemeanors and petty
offenses.
The number of trials conducted in each system is another way
to illustrate the relative size of the two criminal justice systems.
In Colorado, in 2002, there were approximately 40 criminal trials in
federal court, and there were 1,898 criminal trials (excluding
hundreds of quasi-criminal trials in juvenile cases, municipal cases
and infraction cases) in state courts, so only about 2% of criminal
trials took place in federal court. Most jury trials in the United
States (roughly five out of six jury trials conducted in any U.S.
Court) take place in criminal cases in state courts.

At a constitutional level, vis-a-vis the federal government, state constitutions, state law, and local ordinances are all "state law". But within states, state constitutions are superior to all state and local laws, and state laws have priority over local laws except for the state constitution provides otherwise (e.g. in the case of "home rule cities" in areas where local control is granted).
State government legislative power is in principle "plenary" in that it can legislate on any matter not contrary to the U.S. Constitution, validly enacted federal laws, or the state's constitution. States can enact laws on any matter it is not specifically prohibited from enacting laws regarding. In practice, however, the U.S. Constitution, federal laws and regulations, and state constitutions significantly constrain how states may legislate.
Of course, generally, state law is only applicable to matters connected to that state, and local law is only applicable to matters connected to the local government and its territory.

As far as I can understand the building code itself as set out by the
Constitution is fully determined by the States but within a State
there may also be municipal code. There also seem to cases such as NYC
and Chicago where they have their own code and are not subject to
State code. Anyways, you can see my confusion on the subject.

You are indeed confused and everything in the paragraph above is utter gibberish. Basically, the federal government has both a U.S. Code and the Code of Federal Regulations (which is a collection of federal regulations organized by subject-matter). Every states has a state code and often its own code of state regulations. Almost every county or municipality (a term that means city, town, or village) has its own code of ordinances and in larger cities sometimes a code of local regulations as well.

As a bonus, if someone could also explain regulations and how they tie
into code.

A regulation is an interpretation or elaboration of a statute enacted by an executive branch official (the President, the Governor, the Mayor) with the force of law, to the extent that it does not contradict the statute authorizing it.
Building codes are typically so specific that only a few regulations or supplementary ordinances (e.g. adopting the forms to be used in building permits and fee schedules for various local government permits, or the hours of operation of the building permit office) are necessary in connection with them.
Also, courts at the federal level, and in most states, adopt their own rules of procedure, that govern how court cases are handled. Court rules are like regulations, but adopted by the judicial branch rather than by the executive branch.
Don't Forget Case Law
Also, just to be clear, constitutions, statutes, ordinances, and regulations are not the only form of law in the United States. We also have "case law" which includes as a subset the "common law." Case law can be modified by the courts over time under a principle known as stare decisis which means that precedents should be honored and followed but can be changed by the courts when change is appropriate. Precedents of higher courts are superior to precedents from courts that appeal to the higher courts.
When appellate courts made binding rulings on legal issues this creates a precedent that can be used as legal authority in future cases. Some case law interprets constitutions, statutes, ordinances, and regulations. But some case law just proclaims what the law is in a particular area without having any statutory basis, and the "common law" consists of all case law of this type.
In the U.S., most of the law of contract, torts (i.e. civil wrongs like the right to sue a careless driver who causes an accident for negligence), property, and agency is part of the common law, which in the U.S. is derived from English law at the time of the American Revolution, and has developed separate in each state, mostly as a matter of state law, since then. Historically, most criminal law was set forth as common law rather than as statutes, but in modern times, almost all criminal law in the U.S. is codified in statutes.
Most states have statutes that tweak the common law without comprehensively codifying the subject matter of the common law subject tweaked. For example, every state has a statute which sets forth the deadline for suing to enforce common law rights, called a "statute of limitations" without statutorily defining the underlying common law rights (except in Louisiana and Puerto Rico, and to a lesser extent, California, which do codify what would be the common law in other states).
This is relevant even to building codes. For example, one way to enforce a building code violation is by having a local government go to court and seek a permanent injunction against the builder. But the process and substantive standards for granting a permanent injunction are matters of court rules and case law. Likewise, the rules for interpreting building codes are set forth in case law.
Civil Codes Compared

Common law legal systems are shown in red, civil law systems are in blue, Islamic law systems are in green, yellow indicates contributions from local customary law, and other colors indicate hybrid systems such as purple for common law-civil law hybrids.
Countries with what are called "civil law legal systems" don't have any common law. The have civil codes instead of common law, which are all based upon the Napoleonic Civil Code enacted after the French Revolution. But other countries, such as Germany and Spain, enacted civil codes which are similar in concept, but different in structure, detail, and substance, from the French civil code.
Every law and regulation must be rooted in a statute enacted by a legislature in those countries. The bulk of their day to day law is codified in codes such as a "civil code" (and sometimes a "commercial code") that covers most of what the common law does in common law countries. The laws of Louisiana and Puerto Rico are based on the historic French and Spanish civil codes respectively. California's codes are a codification of the  English common law with some concessions to the Mexican civil code (based upon the Spanish civil code) that was in place before it joined the United States. Many other U.S. states in the American Southwest (including Texas) also make concessions in their laws to the pre-existing Mexican civil code.
In Canada, the laws of Quebec are based on the French civil code and are fully codified.

Thank you for the very detailed response! If I may ask a further question – when reading NYC building code the top of the document frequently reads, “Chapter __ was amended by Local Law __ of 20__.” Does that mean local law dictates building code? What would the complete structure be like there?

@EthanDandelion NYC enacts the Local Laws. These alter or amend the NYC building codes. the code is made up from the individual laws.

@EthanDandelion Before statutes are codified into a municipal code they are enacted piecemeal in ordinances that may pass new code portions or may amend existing code portions. A "reference to "Local Law ___ of 20__" is to the city council enactment that passed that amendment which modified the existing building code in that chapter. There would also be a Local Law that adopted that building code in the first place. State and federal laws work the same way. At the federal level they are called "Public Laws" which are codified into the U.S. Code.

you mean particularly high share, right? AFAIK many countries don't codify laws at all....

@littleadv No. Civil law countries (which are the outsized share) codify almost all of their laws. England, the country of origin for the common law, now codifies far more of its law than the U.S. does and the same is true of many countries that hew closer to the British legal tradition, like Canada, Australia, and New Zealand. It is hard to know quite how to classify countries that rely heavily on Islamic law. This leaves a handful of outliers to be compared. What countries don't codify laws at all?

@ohwilleke Countries undergoing a civil war at the moment often enough don't codify the "laws" of their warlords. in a particularly organized fashion, if at all. I'd say the question becomes a little better by adding 3 words: "What functioning constitutionally organized country doesn't codify laws at all?"

@Trish Fair enough, although even warlords often proclaim to keep the same laws in force provisionally.

what a strange map - it has a color for jewish law, but then zooms into europe in a way that completely hides israel where that color would be relevant. I assume the original source has a non-zoomed version too? mind giving a link to the source?

@Syndic It is from WIkipedia. The original is just as bad.

@ohwilleke: unless I've misunderstood, UK law has very little codification, and there is no "UK code" at all. The closest equivalent are consolidation acts, which attempt to bring many previous acts of parliament together into a single act on one subject - but they are relatively few in number.

Did you make that map specifically for this answer?  If it's available elsewhere (especially if there's a vector-graphic version), it would be useful to have a link to it.  (And if someone else made it, you ought to credit appropriately).

@SteveMelnikoff The laws of the U.K. set forth in comprehensive statutes all sorts of things that are purely a matter of common law case law in most U.S. states, especially in the areas of contract and property law.

I am sure you know this but it might worth pointing out that at this point the civil code is only a small part of French law, there are now dozens of codes, many of them created in the last 60-70 years and some very recently, to organize and rationalize existing statutes. Beyond the “partie législative” that consolidates statutes, French codes also contain a “partie réglémentaire” that codifies all sorts of orders, decrees, and regulations originating from the executive branch.

I'll add on to the good answer by @ohwilleke by saying that very often a building code will be the exact text published by the code writing organization such as the National Fire Protection Association. Professionals and trades people will buy the book from the organization, not from their state. The section numbering will be the same in all the states and municipalities that adopted it. (There will be a separate, small publication explaining the differences between the uniform code how it has been adopted in a particular state.)
Other uniform laws, such as the Revised Uniform Law on Notarial Acts, is very similar in the states that adopted it, but each state uses its own section numbering, making it more difficult to discuss by groups of people from different states.
As an example of the importance of the same numbering in different jurisdictions, you could look at the National Electrical Code forum hosted by Mike Holt Enterprises. You will see that around 1/4 of the posts reference a certain section number in the subject line, even though the participants are from all over the US.

And then there's the UCC....

An even better example is the I-Codes – almost every building code implemented across the country is either identical to what the ICC published or with minor amendments!

And, while I didn't mention it my post, the fact that the building codes are protected by copyright and not free open source like all other laws, despite the fact that almost everyone is legally bound to follow them, is deeply problematic. There is minor accommodation made to that fact but it is still very ugly.

Code just means book of laws
One of the early modern "codes" that are very widely known is the "Code Napoléon", aka "Napoleonic Code", officially known as Code Civil des Français, and it is also one of the most influential ones, as the Napoleonic wars brought much of continental Europe into similar lines. It has "siblings" in the slightly older "Allgemeines Landrecht für die Preußischen Staaten", literally called "General Land-Law for the Prussian states" and the "Codex Maximilianeus bavaricus civilis", the "Book of Maximilian's Bavarian Civil [Law]", both of which preceded it. One of the oldest medieval1 European codes that still has the biggest parts preserved is the "Corpus Juris Civilis" (Body of Civil Law), aka Code of Iustinian. It's also known as the "Codex [Iustinian]", though that is technically only the first part, the gathering of the old laws.
This, as well as the CMBC, also shows the origin of the term: Code comes from Codex, an old term for "book". Code in regard to laws has thus grown to be a special legal term with one meaning: A code gathers individual laws or ordinances into a single document, and you then can reference each by paragraph or section and the name of the compilation:

In the practice of law, a code is an organized compilation of existing laws. It is a collection of all the laws in force, including the enacted laws and case law, covering a complete legal system or a specific area. A code can make the formulation of legal principles and rules more concise, clear, and thorough, so that people can understand the rules more quickly and comprehensively.

Often, compilations of laws are translated or named with the word "code" added even if the text does not have an equivalent word mentioned, such as the "Code of Hammurabi" or the "Tang Code" though 唐律 literally translated should be "Tang Law". Other laws are not given that treatment, such as the "lex duodecim tabularum", aka "The Laws of the Twelve Tables". In the latter case, the name describes the shape in which the laws were put on display in the marketplace of Rome.
What's a Building code?
A "Building code" thus is the compilation of laws that pertain building. But there might be several building codes relevant at once: in NYC, there's a bunch of construction code and codes for various utilities, but New York State also has its own Building Code.
A Code by another name
So, a Code is just a compilation of laws. But not all things that are a code are also called a code, and that goes beyond translation inconsistencies. Like, take these examples from the United States of America:

California calls its collected laws the "California Code".
Oregon calls theirs the "Oregon Revised Statutes".
Michigan calls theirs the "Michigan Compiled Laws".
New York uses the term "Consolidated Laws of New York" for the whole book

and everybody just uses the chapter shorthands to refer to its subsections instead: instead of going by the full title Consolidated Laws of New York, Chapter 40 people just say "New York Penal Law" or NY PEN §### or NY UCC §### instead of calling it chapter 38.



Codes can be any type.
The codes you might encounter could contain anything. There are compilations of regulations on what is allowable when or where, such as road or building codes, where breaching is enforced by the state but it's often just a misdemeanor, not a crime. There are compilations of civil laws that regulate what citizens can do to one another and what is a tort when they deal with one another. There are compilations of criminal laws that state what is a crime where the state can prosecute someone. And then there are codes that are a mix of any of that. And to make it even more complicated, not all codes regulate everybody at the same time. So some examples:

the UCC (Uniform Commercial Code), a federal framework of commercial laws that are accepted as state law everywhere in the US - technically it's 50 state laws that just are nigh identical in content (if not order, and setup or wording). It's mostly civil law.
The USC, (United States Code), which contains many federal legislations in their respective chapters (called titles). It's mostly for federal matters, such as copyright (title 17) or patents (title 35). It's a mix of civil laws, regulations and also contains criminal matters, such as 18 USC 1111 - Murder.
The UCMJ (Uniform Code of Military Justice) contains all the special laws that a member of the US armed forces underlies. Unless you are a member of the armed forces, most sections don't apply to you.

Codes can be anywhere in the hierarchy
Remember the UCC I mentioned up there? It's a subsection of the California Code, which is only superseded by the California constitution, as far as California state law is concerned. But the LA-County Building Code is at the lowest end of California's construction laws.
And technically... Constitutions also are codes, as they compile laws. And in the case of the UK, the term "constitutional code" was used in 2014 to try to clarify its quite complex situation of what is its constitution.

1 - That's a technicality: The end of Antiquity and the Medieval Era are set to change around 400.

Nitpicking an otherwise good answer: the Napoleonic code is influential (due to its imposition in European countries counquered during the Napoleonic wars), but it is definitely not one of the older codes. There were codes before the modern era (in Babylonia, in the Roman and Chinese empires; some forms of religious law resembled civil codes). Even excluding those as too foreign to modern sensibilities, the Allgemeines Landrecht für die Preußischen Staaten is a very similar and earlier effort.

@UJM Indeed, and adjusted for that. The problem with antique and non-european laws is, that we often slap "code" into the name, even if they are not named code, in translating them.

The sloppiness on terms of law in the US is utterly reprehensible.  There should be no ambiguity on terms like "ordinance", "law", "code", "statute", "misdemeanor", "felony" and so forth.  But most citizens don't really understand them, except "law" (you break, you get cited or go to jail).
For this sloppiness on terms, you can thank your Supreme Court for not educating citizens and reigning in the perpetual misuse (and abuse) of terms by police, lawyers, citizens and others.
Only the "law" counts and an "ordinance" is generally used for lower-government laws (not federal) while the word "code" is not a law at all until it is made into a bill ("Building Codes X shall be required for all structures built.") and signed into Law.  Until then, it remains an executive or legislative directive/order (or set of "best practices") that could be ignored without breaking the Law.
In a "free" country like the US, it is unwise that such codes are signed into law, because we're a country of equals and the government could simply endorse them as best practices and gift such standards to citizens for the benefit of all, but this is typically not what happens.  It needs fixed.

"But most citizens don't really understand them, except "law" (you break, you get cited or go to jail)." You clearly don't understand what the term "law" means.

@ohwilleke:  Calm down, I was giving a stupid example of what the average citizen understands about the law.  What you should be passionate about is fixing our broken system (or demolishing like Jefferson said).  Then, you could get some authority.

Roseblitt-Janssen The belief that all law is criminal law is a common misconception. As someone who has practiced law since 1995, worked on only three criminal cases (and only one solo), I can speak from personal experience to say that this simply isn't true. See contract, torts, probate law, civil tax law, property law, family law, etc.

Your profile:I claim a Doctor of the Law. If you want to be a master of written law, you can go to school and get a PhD (Law). Otherwise, a qualified JD is not given by any school known. In theory, a JD could been earned with a level of gravitas for a national level of authority, but as the US has already failed, one can only conclude that there are NO such qualified individuals or degrees. This JD is for the prophesy of novus ordo seclorum: a world democracy. "Seclorum" should be interpreted as like "ratiocination": reason, not divine dispensation or such, but a system created through reason.

@ohwilleke:  As for my profile:  did you have some dispute with it?  I see I misspelled a word...
